ReactJS: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
I have the following:
const categorizedDatas2 = maam.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { id, Category, CategoryId, SubCategory, SubCategoryId, Name, Brand, Owner, RealOwner, packingLocation, Quantity, Weight, Status } = curr;
    const categorymatch = Object.values(newata?.GearCategories).filter(chunk => chunk.id === CategoryId)
    const realcat = categorymatch[0].label
    if (!acc[Owner]) {
      acc[Owner] = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    acc[Owner].items.push({ id, Category, CategoryId, SubCategory, SubCategoryId, Name, Brand, Owner, RealOwner, packingLocation, Quantity, Weight, Status });
    return acc;
  }, {});

categorymatch is returning the error:
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
console.log of newata?.GearCategories gives me several undefined but am not sure how to skip or ignore these?

Can you check this
const categorizedDatas2 = maam.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { id, Category, CategoryId, SubCategory, SubCategoryId, Name, Brand, Owner, RealOwner, packingLocation, Quantity, Weight, Status } = curr;

    // Check if newata and newata.GearCategories are defined
    if (newata && newata.GearCategories) {
        const categorymatch = Object.values(newata.GearCategories).filter(chunk => chunk.id === CategoryId);
        
        // Check if categorymatch has at least one element
        if (categorymatch.length > 0) {
            const realcat = categorymatch[0].label;

            if (!acc[Owner]) {
                acc[Owner] = {
                    items: [],
                };
            }

            acc[Owner].items.push({ id, Category, CategoryId, SubCategory, SubCategoryId, Name, Brand, Owner, RealOwner, packingLocation, Quantity, Weight, Status });
        }
    }

    return acc;
}, {});


Perfect - thank you!
